# Test the view that is showing after authorisation

Tags: laravel, testing

I am learning how to do simple tests on my application. Simply, I dont know how to get over the problem below.

Problem:

[image: Problem]

I am just trying to see, if my page is loading correctly by checking if site contain word "Send". Send is my button that is located in my view.

How can I check the view as a logged user?

My test function:

```
public function testSiteIsLoadingCorrectly()
{
    $response = $this->get('/homepage');
    $response->assertSee("Send");
}
```

After some research I got this function:

```
public function testSiteIsLoadingCorrectly() {
        $user = User::factory()->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                         ->withSession(['banned' => false])
                         ->get('/');

        $response->assertSee("Welcome on my page!");
    }
```

It works great but only for "/". If I give another route, my console is showing a lot of text and finally it doesn't work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using version 8.17.2

Comment: see if this helps you https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication

Comment: Ok i will look into that.

Comment: Works! I got another problem. I thought that when I give another route to get method, it will works also, but it doesnt.

Comment: $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                         ->withSession(['banned' => false])
                         ->get('/anotherPage');

Comment: My console is showing a lot of text which is unreadable.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

assertSee() works bad with polish chars like ą,ę,ć etc...
That's the reason of all problems.

PS.
"Send" in Polish means "Wyślij"...